# Migrating RichFaces SerializableDataModel implementation to custom DataModel implementation

Tags: jsf-2, datatable, lazy-loading, visitor-pattern

I have been tasked with migrating JSF 1.x with RichFaces 3.x on JSP to JSF 2.x on Facelets. The previous developer used [RichFaces `<rich:dataTable>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?tab=dataModel&cid=115467). As data a bean was sent to the table. This bean was a [`SerializableDataModel`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/apidoc_framework/org/ajax4jsf/model/SerializableDataModel.html) which has a [`walk()`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/apidoc_framework/org/ajax4jsf/model/ExtendedDataModel.html#walk(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20org.ajax4jsf.model.DataVisitor,%20org.ajax4jsf.model.Range,%20java.lang.Object)) method allowing you to easily traverse the data table using the visitor pattern. This also allowed the table to only load data needed using lazy loading. We have over 216k rows of data and all of them are loaded when the page loads or when you try to change pages to view the next set of rows.

I thus need to migrate this to JSF 2.x. I have never used JSF 2.x before and I am simply asking if anyone has ever experience this, how they solved it and if they can give me some resources to get started.

I can not share more as it is against my works policies.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{records}" var="record" rows="20"
                    class="table table-striped"
                    styleClass="dataTableRecords dataListTable" rowClasses="odd, even"
                    id="dataTableRecords" rendered="#{records.rowCount > 0}">
</h:dataTable>
```

```java
@ManagedBean(name="records")
@RequestScoped

public class Records extends BseDataModel{...}
```

BseDataModel is what contained our `walk` method, it now extends `DataModel`

If you think you can help please let me know, I can give some more limited information, if you need it please ask.

Comment: Why not upgrading RichFaces as well to a JSF 2.x compatible 4.x version?

Comment: @BalusC I'd have to say, ask my boss. I was told we had some RichFaces that was being upgraded to work with jsf2 but it was scrapped. Not really sure why. Also thank you for editing this, you are able to get my point across better than I am.